# Return a value if input matches a element in array of objects in java

Tags: java

I would like to return value `1` if the input matches any of the id elements in the array of objects or else return `-1`.
For example for 
`27 
vjxiyhc
kyoyfsl
34
oguybhh
cuaxany
10
oxhdjcs
gvhtlzw
19
thamkrf
arijclh
32
cvljyye
heijkiv
34`
 output should be `1`. If the last input is `25`, output should be `-1`.
The code given below is not working properly. It only checks the id value of the last input into the array. If I put `27`or `10` or `19` it still returns `-1`. Only `32` returns `1`. Please suggest changes.

```
public class LibraryDemo 
{
public static Library[] searchLibraryById(Library[] objArray, int inputid)
{
    int out=0;
    for(int i=0;i<objArray.length;i++)
    {
        if (objArray[i].id==inputid)
        {
            out=1;
        }
        else 
        {
            out=-1;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(out);
    return objArray;
}
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    Library[] objArray=new Library[5];

    for(int i=0;i<objArray.length;i++)
    {
        int id=sc.nextInt();sc.nextLine();
        String name=sc.nextLine();
        String address=sc.nextLine();
        objArray[i]=new Library(id,name,address);
    }

    int inputid=sc.nextInt();
    searchLibraryById(objArray, inputid);
}
}

class Library
{
int id;
String name;
String address;

public int getId()
{
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id=id;
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name=name;
}
public String getAddress()
{
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address)
{
    this.address=address;
}

public Library(int id,String name, String address)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.address=address;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break out of your loop once the input value is found. `out` is getting overwritten because you continue to check remaining array indices even after a match has been found

```
for(int i=0;i<objArray.length;i++)
{
    if (objArray[i].id==inputid)
    {
        out=1;
        break; // found match, break out of loop
    }
    else 
    {
        out=-1;
    }
}
System.out.print(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not breaking out of the for Loop after the match. you can do it more efficiently if the array has large no of objects using parallel streams. Refer code below.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

 public static Library[] searchLibraryById(Library[] objArray, int inputid)
    {
        List<Library> lib = Arrays.asList(objArray).parallelStream()
                .filter(obj -> obj.id == inputid).collect(toList());
        int out = lib.size() != 0 ? 1 : -1;
        System.out.println(out);
        return objArray;
    }
```